# Making line chart of MIS using python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following dataframe with date as index

```
               Apples        Oranges       Strawberries
07-13-2020      1              5              10
07-14-2020      1              17              4
```

I have to make the line chart of above dataframe with number of fruits on the Y axis and dates on the x axis.

```
df.plot(x=df.index,y=["Apples","Oranges","Strawberries"],kind="line") is not working
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Try converting your pandas index to datetime format and try again as below:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%m-%d-%Y', errors='ignore')
df.plot(kind="line")
```

Answer (score 0):

That's `df.plot.line()`. The index is automatically the `x` axis, and the columns are the groups.

Comment: I tried that but I am getting blank chart with the Userwarning: Attempting to set identical left==right results

Answer (score 0):

df.plot.line()
https://matplotlib.org/  dedicated libraries for this you can learn.